# Bubble notices through redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, controller

**My scenario:**

In my controller, after confirming the user, I redirect to root (a landing page: `statics#landing`) and I attach a notice:

```
redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Confirmation successful.'
```

but there, I always check if the user is already signed in, and if so I'm redirecting him to the actual index:

```
def landing
  redirect_to actual_index_url if (user.signed_in?)
end
```

How can I propagate the confirmation notice to the last page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `flash.keep`.

http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.8rc1/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#M006014

Comment: This seems more Rails idiomatic: more details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```rb
def landing
  redirect_to actual_index_url, :notice => flash[:notice] if (user.signed_in?)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`flash.keep(:notice)` - if you want to keep only notices just `flash.keep` will keep both `:notices` and `:errors`.